# Android : get the view position by a <key,value> pair

Tags: android, json, view, hashmap, android-viewholder

In my app application i have an API that parsing **JSON** updating **500 rows** is the list view. In a row I have id,name,number and status. Through the pushnotification am getting an **id** out of the 500 and I want update the status of that id having row.

Am using **getter/setter** method here so if getting the view position i can update the row.

This is the way am parsing

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
      String phone = c.getString("phone");
      String subDistributorStatus = c.getString("status");
      String name = c.getString("firstName");        
      subDistributerId = c.getString("subDistributerId");

      SubdistributorItem item = new SubdistributorItem();
      item.setSubDistributorName(name);
      item.setSubDistributorNumber(phone);
      item.setSubDistributorStatus(subDistributorStatus);
      item.setSubDistributorId(subDistributerId);
   }
```

This is the way am updating single row

```
SubdistributorItem subdistributorItem = subdistributorItemList.get(Integer.parseInt(getFromPreference("Sub_position")));  
String phone= subdistributorItem.getSubDistributorNumber();
String id= subdistributorItem.getSubDistributorId();
String status= subdistributorItem.getSubDistributorStat
```

Here am getting the position by clicking the view. 
Now if i get one of the **id** in the row  is there any chance to get the **position** in the view.

I tried HashMap.

**HashMap newmap = new HashMap(); // in global

newmap.put(subDistributerId,i);  // in loop

Log.e("Tag ","hash map positon "+ newmap.get(43)); // in onResume**

But failed.

can any please help to get the **position** of the **row** ,if get **id** of the row.

Comment: I guess here it is what you are looking for , http://stackoverflow.com/a/18016073/2509009

Comment: how can i get the position in the arrayList if i gave an ID  @asadnwfp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ArrayList along with the getter/setter class. You also have to extend the BaseAdapter class to get the string values of a particular position and map it to the view.

You can check the following example --

The below code will loop through the JSON and set the values using Setter methods and then it will add them to the ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<SubdistributorItem> listitem = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
  String phone = c.getString("phone");
  String subDistributorStatus = c.getString("status");
  String name = c.getString("firstName");        
  subDistributerId = c.getString("subDistributerId");

  SubdistributorItem item = new SubdistributorItem();
  item.setSubDistributorName(name);
  item.setSubDistributorNumber(phone);
  item.setSubDistributorStatus(subDistributorStatus);
  item.setSubDistributorId(subDistributerId);

  listitem.add(item);
  }
```

Then extend the BaseAdapter class to get the individual position and the values associated with it.

```
public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public Context ba_context;
public ArrayList<SubdistributorItem> listitem = new ArrayList<>();
public LayoutInflater inflater;
ListRowItem currentlistitem;

public MyBaseAdapter(Context ma_context, ArrayList<SubdistributorItem> ma_listitem) {
    super();
    this.ba_context = ma_context;
    this.listitem = ma_listitem;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) ba_context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.listitem.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return this.listitem.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return (long) position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;

    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_layout, parent, false);

    TextView carrier = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.layout_textview1);

    currentlistitem = listitem.get(position);

    String str_carrier = currentlistitem.getCarrier();

    carrier.setText(str_carrier);

    return vi;
}
}
```

Finally call this class and set the adapter in the listview somewhere in your code as per your requirement.

```
baseAdapter = new MyBaseAdapter(context,listitem);
listView.setAdapter(baseAdapter);
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: am using RecyclerView.Adapter , also am looking for get a position in the arrayList if gave ID, ID is one of the content in the arrayList @Saumik Bhattacharya

Comment: @BinilS -- How many times `listitem.add(item)` will be executed, the data will be associated in subsequent positions. Are you looking for the position of the item on which you have clicked?

Comment: you where right, but if I am going to find an id from the array list , and the array list size is 1000 , it cause long time of execution.I found the solution by using HashMap. Thanks for your help @Saumik Bhattacharya

Comment: @BinilS -- Thats great! :) If my answer has helped you, please up-vote the answer. Thanks! :)