# Getting zero element in listview without using the onsetclicklistener

Tags: android

I want to get the zero element postion in a listView without using the onclick listeners is there a way to do that.

Expected results
Get zero element position in a listview automatically without clicking the element

Comment: I have edited the question please read and help

Comment: **when** do you want to get it?

Comment: maybe [THAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18016048/android-get-position-of-item-in-a-listview-given-its-id) can help you.

Comment: your are contradicting yourself. you don't want to do onClick and you want to get zero number element. So point out the event and simple get the zero number element using `listVariable.get(0)`. Try to write the clear detail in your description.

Comment: I need the app to compare time of the the element in zero postion (I get this from SQLite database) with system time thats why I wouldnt want to click for it to work

Comment: SO **when** do you want to do that? After what happens?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(yourList.size!=0)
{
  yourObject=yourList.get(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be like

```
if(yourList.size > 0)
{
  yourObject=yourList.get(0);
}
```